# How can i set the output keyPress to the same input field?

Tags: jquery, keypress

I am trying to get the user keypress output and set it to the same input.

However in my `input` result I get the output twice. For example, if the user presses `d` I see `Dd`. How can I solve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test").keypress(function(e) {
    let key = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    let upperCaseKey = (key.toUpperCase())
    $("#test").val(upperCaseKey);
    $("#test").css("width", "25px")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text class="myid" id="test" />
```

Comment: You need to prevent the default/system keypress event:  `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type=text class="myid" id="test" />




$(".myid").on('keypress', function(evt) {
  $(this).val(function (_, val) {
    return val + String.fromCharCode(evt.which).toUpperCase();
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding explanation of how and why they work.

Comment: will take care  of this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is to force the value input by the user to be uppercase you can simply call `toUpperCase()` on the `value`:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("#test").on('input', e => e.target.value = e.target.value.toUpperCase());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text class="myid" id="test" />
```

Note the use of the `input` event here. This is because it will also cover text which is copied in to the field using the mouse.